# Is there something wrong with using "said (that)" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, tenses

Quick context, work as a translator.

I had a short blurb I had to translate where I basically rendered it as:

> "Bob spoke about how Countryland was one of the countries that
> suffered greatly from the Big Bad Thing, and that he wanted to hold a
> photograph exhibition in Hereland."

(Names and places changed for privacy/company policy reasons)

Is there anything wrong with making it "said that Countryland..." Is it ungrammatical? If so, what would be the correct word(s) to use?

My proofreader initially changed "spoke about how" to "told that" which was ungrammatical, so I told her that, to which she responded "change it to 'said or said that' then", which I felt was wrong but could not explain why.

All the stuff I came across online explained that:

- "Say" is when you pronounce words, express a thought/opinion, for stating a fact, affirming something, declaring something, etc. and is also a one-way sort of action, i.e. doesn't necessarily imply there's more than one person in the situation at hand. It is also doesn't take a person as its object, not without some modifying/adding extra words.
- "Tell" is for giving information to somebody through speaking or writing and needs a person after it as the object. Unlike Say, it is a "two-way" sort of action, where it implies the existence of two parties conversing with each other.
- "Speak" is for languages and for general conversation, no specific details usually expressed.
- "Talk" is more or less the same as speak, but more informal.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As written, it's a bit unclear what you're actually trying to ask us here. Could you possibly edit the question to make it more obvious? Maybe a structure like "My proofreeder told me to change X to Y, but Y seems ungrammatical to me. Is Y grammatical? What is the correct form for me to use in this context?"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with *spoke about how Countryland was*, although you could change it to *spoke about Countryland being* if you don't like the presence of *how*. Personally, the only thing I noticed is that I'd tend to say *photography exhibit* rather than *photograph exhibition*. But that's just personal preference.

Comment: @ymbirtt Sorry for the lack of clarity, I edited my question, is it okay like this?

Comment: @JasonBassford I figured it wasn't wrong, but I need to be able to explain why that's the case otherwise it won't fly with my co-worker.

Comment: Yes, much better. It might be worth removing some of the fluff telling the story of all the research you did, since it doesn't directly add to the question. Summarising what you already know as a few bullet points before the actual question is useful, but right now your question is buried somewhere in the middle of a fairly substantial text wall.

Comment: Both are fine ('said that' and 'spoke about') But 'spoke about' could mean he spoke about the topic in general 'Said that' is just repeating the words he used or perhaps a paraphrase if it's not direct speech. With 'tell' you need to add an object pronoun: 'told me' etc.

Comment: The text as given isn't syntactically valid, because there's no "main verb" *(**speak about, say, tell**, etc.)* in the second clause (after the comma). This can be fixed by changing the first verb to *Bob **said [that]** Countryland was...,* in which case we can reasonably delete some or all of the implied highlighted repetitions in *...and [**he said that**] he wanted...* This problem arises because the syntax of initial ***spoke about*** doesn't match the "repeating" context of the second clause, so it can't be "deleted" as per my "to say [that]" alternative.

Comment: Note that it's *possible* (but probably not stylistically *desirable*) to use ***to speak*** in the second clause, but personally I'd normally expect a different preposition there *(...and [he] **spoke of wanting** to hold an exhibition)*. Which gets you tied up in stylistic knots if you try to "delete repeated / predictable elements". But this all looks like opinion-based *writing advice* to me (and if there ***is*** a meaningful underlying On Topic question here, it should probably be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: I wouldn't ask why it's *right* so much as try to get your coworker to explain why they think it's *wrong*. There are many things that are right, simply because that's how we say things. On the other hand, we can more easily explain things that are wrong. All of these are fine: *I spoke about how to do X.* *I spoke about why X was done.* *I spoke about many things, including the how and why of X.*

Comment: If your proofreader changed it to "Bob told that Countryland was ..." then you absolutely need a new proofreader and you shouldn't feel the need to justify anything to them.

Comment: @Jim Well to play devil's advocate she's a native Japanese person and the only Japanese person in my department who comprehends written English extremely well. For the most part she doesn't usually come up with strange corrections like that, but it happens, and if I can't explain explicitly why it's not correct, then she can't let me just change something willy nilly since I could be wrong as far as she knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the phrase **spoke about how** to **described how** and the problem becomes clearer:

> He described  how the roof leaked and that he wanted to fix it.

If you don't add the verb **said**, --  *and **said** that he wanted to fix it*, you have a  clause introduced by *that* just dangling there. It doesn't act as a second clause that **how**  governs:

*He described how that he wanted to fix it. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

*He spoke about how that he wanted to fix if.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>

You need to strike **that**.

> He described how he wanted to fix it.
>
> He spoke about how he wanted to fix it.

Or if your intention is not to say that he went on to talk about the details of the repair he envisioned, but only that it was his intention to fix the leak, you would eliminate **how** and change **described** to **said**:

> He said he wanted to fix it.

In your example, it is not clear whether you want **how** to govern *that he wanted to hold a photograph exhibition in Hereland*.  If that is your intention, strike **that** and consider repeating **how**:

> Bob spoke about how Countryland sucked and  (how) he wanted to hold a photograph exhibition in Hereland.

If I had to focus on one thing, it would be how to use the word **how**

Many native speakers use **how** fairly sloppily to introduce a bare statement of fact:

> I told you how I like chocolate.

when it would be more idiomatic (more "mainstream") to use **that** there:

> I told you that I like chocolate. <sup>"that" is optional</sup>

For the sake of clarity, if you're not speaking about the *manner* or *details* or  *degree* of something, but merely stating the bare fact, use *that* not *how* to introduce the statement of fact.

Thus, you might consider changing "spoke about how" in your first clause to something else, like **stated** or **said**:

> Bob stated that Countryland sucked and that he wanted to hold ...

unless you mean to say that Bob described *in some detail* how Countryland sucked or *the particular manner* or *degree to which*  Countryland sucked:

> Bob went on and on  about **how** Countryland sucked and **how** he wanted to hold a photography exposition in Hereland.

And always check to see if the sentence would be clearer if **how** is repeated when you have clauses joined by **and** in such a sentence.

In that last sentence  about Bob, the word **about** could be eliminated. If it isn't eliminated, you ought to repeat **how**, since **about** becomes the governor of what follows and "about ... he wanted to hold a photography exposition" is ungrammatical. To eliminate that jarring effect where the reader or listener has to "mentally" repeat **how** to make the statement grammatical, the writer or speaker can proactively repeat **how**. Doing so  makes the sentence  clearer and eases the burden of the reader or listener.

```
  about 
      how 
         X

        and

  (about)
      (how) 
          Y
```

becomes

```
about

     how
       X

     and

 (about)

     how 
       Y
```

Answer (score 1):

"He said [that]" followed by a clause is fine, although 'that' might also be the first word of the following clause.

"He told that" followed by a clause is bad (although grammatical), because it is likely to create a 'garden path' where the reader expects an indirect object before the object clause.